# Rearrange rows of arbitrary data and columns in Deedle

Tags: f#, deedle

I would like to rearrange row values to columns. In [Rearrange rows and columns in Deedle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70937857/rearrange-rows-and-columns-in-deedle/70948358#70948358) this was done via `Frame.pivotTable`. The targeted value was of type `int` such that the series could be aggregated by `Sum()`.
How to pivot arbitrary types like strings or dates and preserve missing values?

For example

```ml
open Deedle

let str = "Key;Attribute;Value\nK1;A;01.01.2000\nK1;B;\nK2;A;02.02.2020\nK2;B;03.03.2030"
let bytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes str
let stream =  new MemoryStream( bytes )

let df =
    Frame.ReadCsv(
        stream = stream,
        separators = ";",
        hasHeaders = true
    )

df.Print(true)
```

```
     Key      Attribute Value                
     (string) (string)  (DateTime)           
0 -> K1       A         1/1/2000 12:00:00 AM 
1 -> K1       B         <missing>            
2 -> K2       A         2/2/2020 12:00:00 AM 
3 -> K2       B         3/3/2030 12:00:00 AM
```

```ml
let df1 = 
    df
    |> Frame.pivotTable 
        (fun k r -> r.GetAs<string>("Key")) 
        (fun k r -> r.GetAs<string>("Attribute")) 
        (fun frm -> frm.GetColumn("Value").Sum())  //<-- Different aggregation needed

df1.Print(true)
```

Result should be

```
      A                     B                                   
      (DateTime)            (DateTime)                          
K1 -> 1/1/2000 12:00:00 AM  <missing>            
K2 -> 2/2/2020 12:00:00 AM  3/3/2030 12:00:00 AM
```

Answer (score 0):

I think there are two problems here. One is that you need an aggregation function that works with `DateTime`, and the other is that you need a way to handle missing values in the input. (The original SO question you linked to doesn't have the second issue.)

The first problem is easy to deal with. For example, `TryMin` will return an `Option<DateTime>` instead of a `float`:

```ml
let df1 = 
    df
    |> Frame.pivotTable 
        (fun k r -> r.GetAs<string>("Key")) 
        (fun k r -> r.GetAs<string>("Attribute")) 
        (fun frm ->
            frm.GetColumn("Value").TryMin()
                |> Option.toNullable<DateTime>)
```

Result is:

```
      A                    B
      (Nullable`1)         (Nullable`1)
K1 -> 1/1/2000 12:00:00 AM <missing>
K2 -> 2/2/2020 12:00:00 AM 3/3/2030 12:00:00 AM
```

This isn't quite what you want, though, because the values are now of type `Nullable<DateTime>` instead of just `DateTime`. Unfortunately, I don't know of a way around this using `pivotTable`, but someone else who knows more about Deedle might be able to help.